# Caching last entires of stream data

Tags: mysql, hadoop, redis, cassandra, hbase

I am going to work on a distributed application. The data is going to be streamed and analyzed. Also, the end users need to have access to the last streamed data as quickly as possible. Also, I need to keep back-up of the data as well as worked on it.

My initial idea is as follows:
1) Keep redis as a cache to hold the last entries.
2) MySQL - storing data
3) Hadoop/Hbase - convenient way of storing data to analyze it.

What do you think of such a setup? Would you recommend anything else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think a combination of Spark and Cassandra would be an excellent way to go. Cassandra can easily handle the data throughput and storage. Spark provides lightning quick analytics.

Comment: It looks like DataStax [just announced](http://www.datastax.com/2014/12/datastax-announces-dse-4-6-the-leading-database-platform) support for Spark Streaming which might be exactly what you're looking for. I understand they have a spark streaming demo in there that could give you an idea of how it would all fit together.